# How to make a double Inner Join in django?

Tags: python, mysql, django, orm, inner-join

I have a django aplication that have to show the country name and the city name of a "need" in the list of candidate.
To explain this better I have the next picture:
[image]

So, here is the process:
First, someone posts a "need" with their respective country and city.
The city and the country are in diferent model.

Then, the candidate can make an offer to resolve that need.

I want to see in a list, all the offers I send to the need (just 1 offer to 1 need) but in my html template I want to display the name of the country and the city of the need.

Here is my **models.py**

```
class requiter (models.Model):
    requiter_name = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)

class country (models.Model):
    country_name = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)

class city (models.Model):
    city_name = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)

class candidate (models.Model):
    full_name=models.CharField(max_length=230, null=True)

class need(models.Model):
    requiter = models.ForeignKey(requiter, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    title= models.CharField(max_length=300, null=True)
    description=models.TextField(null=True)
    country=models.ForeignKey(country, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    city=models.ForeignKey(city, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)

class offer(models.Model):
    need = models.ForeignKey(need, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    candidate = models.ForeignKey(candidate, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
```

and here is my **views.py**

```
def candidateprofile(request):
    candata = candidate.objects.get(id=request.session['account_id'])
    #HERE IS WHERE I WANT TO TAKE ALL THE OFFERS THAT THE CANDIDATE MADE, AND THE NAME OF THE COUNTRY AND CITY IN THE NEEDS
    myoffers = offer.objects.filter(candidate_id = request.session['account_id'] )
    #??????
    dic.update({'candata': candata, 'jobapplies': jobapplies})
    return render(request, 'my_app/candidateProfile.html', dic)
```

In SQL the equivalent is next:

```
SELECT o.need_id, n.title, r.recruiter_name, c.country_name, y.city_name FROM offer AS o
INNER JOIN need AS n ON o.need_id = n.id
INNER JOIN requiter AS r ON n.recruiter_id = r.id
INNER JOIN country AS c ON n.country_id = c.id
INNER JOIN city AS y ON n.city_id = y.id
WHERE o.candidate_id = sended_parameter
```

But I don't know how to do it in django. Please Help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not be thinking in these terms. You should be thinking in terms of how you get the objects that you want. In your case, you want the Need objects that refer to the candidates offers. So:

```
needs = Need.objects.filter(offer__candidate=request.session['candidate_id'])
```

Now you can iterate through needs and get `need.country.country_name` and `need.city.city_name`; this will be inefficient, because it will cause a query on each access, so we can add `select_related` to the query:

```
needs = needs.select_related('country', 'city')
```